# Need to load the URL from excel and need to execute using Ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, import-from-excel

I am very new to ruby, i wanted to learn the ruby code. I have basic knowledge.
I have list of pages(URL), I saved in an excel. I wanted to get those pages and needs to load in browser. Please find below basic script which I wrote for page loading.

```
require 'rubygems'

require 'watir'

ie = Watir::IE.new

ie.goto("http://google.com")

ie.goto("http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/")

ie.goto("http://www.onestoptesting.com/manual-testing/")

ie.goto("https://facebook.com")
```

Please help to get it done.

Thanks and Regards,
Vinayaka M N

Comment: Have you tried anything for reading in the urls? Is the input in .csv or .xls format?

Comment: where are you having a problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Nokogiri gem and xml/ json file.
For exmaple:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'nokogiri'

browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open('your_file.xml'))
url = doc.at('//url').text

browser.goto(url)
```

And you must have xml like this:

```
<url>http://google.com</url>
```